# Using jquery-addresspicker in a Symfony 2 form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps, symfony

I'm using the plugin [jquery-addresspicker](http://xilinus.com/jquery-addresspicker/demos/index.html) with a Symfony 2 form to collect the selected longitude/latitude. Although the lng/lat fields are populated, after the form is submitted I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Field lat cannot be empty (null)
```

Here is part of my form:

```
<label>Lat:</label> 
{{form_widget(form.lat, {attr: {'disabled':'disabled'}})}} <br/>
<label>Lng:</label> 
{{form_widget(form.lng, {attr: {'disabled':'disabled'}})}} <br/>
```

[image: screen shot of long decimal[2]]

Comment: Pleace place your asserts to fields, and show your form type

Comment: Thank you Barett please I couldn't show it on stackoverflow (validation of indentation ...) but go to the following adress please: http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1542141/php/bibliotheques-frameworks/symfony2/utiliser-plugin-jquery-address-picker-symfony2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to remove the attribute in "desabled" defined in the form field