# installation of OhGoogleMapFormTypeBundle

Tags: jquery, symfony, jquery-ui

I'm installing the bundle https://github.com/ollieLtd/OhGoogleMapFormTypeBundle to set longititude and latitude from the google map but I'm still getting this error : Variable "id" does not exist in OhGoogleMapFormTypeBundle:Form:google_maps.html.twig at line 4
all though I've configure the bundle as mentioned in it documentation

my CompanyType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    ->add('latlng', 'oh_google_maps')
    ;
}
```

and my View:

```
{% extends "OhGoogleMapFormTypeBundle:Form:google_maps.html.twig" %}
{% block oh_google_maps_callback %}
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var oh_google_maps_callback = function(location, gmap){
                // logs to the console your new latitude
                console.log('Your new latitude is: '+location.lat());
            }
        </script>   
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Did take a look at the repo, and seems like a bug to me. The view probably tries to access the view variables. Think you should report this at the Github repo.

Comment: I've done it already https://github.com/ollietb/OhGoogleMapFormTypeBundle/issues/28 but nobody has answer since long time

Comment: Please can you help me to fixe this bug ? or you know someone that can help me ? I'll thank the person. He just need to tell me how much (in dollar)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've integrated [The plugin](http://xilinus.com/jquery-addresspicker/demos/index.html) from scratch and it's working well

Comment: This is not the **best** answer to your question. It doesn't solve the problem! Downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$builder->add('latlng', 'oh_google_maps', array('id' => 'some_string'));
```

Comment: I try it but doesn't work also the bundle have it own options you can see them: https://github.com/ollietb/OhGoogleMapFormTypeBundle

Comment: I see that there is missing `id` option in this file https://github.com/ollieLtd/OhGoogleMapFormTypeBundle/blob/master/Form/Type/GoogleMapType.php  in `buildView` method, and `setDefaultOptions` as well.

Comment: It's truly an emergency that's why if you or you know somone that can fixe the bug or can install it successfully with then I'll thank him (some dollar...) me and for me indeed I've install and use this bundle in past but I don't know how I can get the old version

Comment: Yes ! I even try to pass the id variable in the array but didn't success

Comment: you can hack that file or template until they fix it, or everride formType and add missing option.

Comment: I've passed all the form options to the view from the controller including the id variable I just set for any value (2) and now I get this error: Method "lat" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in OhGoogleMapFormTypeBundle:Form:google_maps.html.twig at line 47

Comment: In this line in template `'default_zoom'` set just 15 or 5 or I don't know, shitty bundle, better make you own form extension with that functionality...

Comment: Yes this is what I though to do absolutly but unfortunatly I've been stop at that level please malcon look at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530289/using-jquery-addresspicker-in-a-symfony-2-form?noredirect=1#comment52921526_32530289

Comment: About the bundle now the form is display but the lat and lng field and the map are not displayed

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to replace `{{ id }}` with `{{ form.vars.id }}`? That should make use of the FormType's view variables. The `id` should be set over there by default.